# Layout dynamic grid in middle

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, layout, android-linearlayout

I have a grid with (currently) four cells wide. Each cell I am specifying to be 20px wide. I want to position this in the middle and at the top of a portrait layout.
My code is below. My problem is that hte grid seems to fill the whole width whereas it want it to just take number of columns * column width only. And for white space around it. 
I've put colours on each of the components to try and make it easy to see where each one is. The two views in the first LinearLayout are never shown. Ive tried

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
           android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
           android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
           android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           tools:context=".EntryPointFragment">

<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF00"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/grid_view"
              android:background="#FF000000"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:numColumns="4"
              android:columnWidth="30dp"
              android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
              android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
              android:gravity="center"/>

    <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFF00FF"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>

<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF00FFFF"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This image shows the sort of thing I want.

Can anyone help me tweak this xml? The number of columns and rows in the grid will vary so the space around it should dynamically resize.

Thanks
[image: My Ideal Layout]

Comment: is this an exerpt? you are missing at least another linear layout as a parent to all these views (vertical)

Comment: you wont need gravity (it influences the views content not its arrangement), the views surrounding the gridview should have a height either fixed or match_parent. Also your linearlayout should use the height of full screen since this is what you want :) (match_parent)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I've updated the code snippet now. ive removed graivty and added the out LinearLayout. not sure what happened with copy and paste. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#ffff00">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid_view"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:numColumns="4"
            android:columnWidth="20dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:background="#FFFF00FF"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF00FFFF"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

You will get something like that:

[image: Example of wanted layout]

BTW: you can change the width/height of your GridView as you wish, you can put there a weight too with a similar approach as for the views next to it.

Comment: Thanks @Matcoil for the answer. I do want to change to have the width and height dynamic depending on the data that is in the datasource. I'll play with the layout_width/layout_height to see if I can get it as I want. Ideally I want the cell width to be 20px and the width and height auto calculated depending on the data